# Is Moriah ever a man's name and why not, there's many Tzion's

Tags: names, baby-infant

I've never met a Moriah but there are many kids named Tziyyon.
Everything is masculine about it except the bitterness (kabbalisticly the Avoda of the male is too sweeten the judgements, להמתיק דינים which are rooted in Gevura,
the feminine or left side Sfira, typically). So is there a historic man Moriah for example in the Talmud or other Jewish texts, and if no, could it be a man's name and if not why not. The root Mar, bitter or "to change something" is male. And the bitterness does not seem to be an answer because we see Moshe Rabbeinu named his son Gershon (expulsion, or stranger). Also the close root Mar has positive meanings like master, teacher. And again the root מור like the sap, myrhh, is male. Also just a mountain, Har, is male and even signifies the Avot as in, "I lift up mine eyes to the Mountains" and the commentators say: the Patriarchs Abraham etc.

Comment: Words ending kamatz-heh are generally feminine

Comment: Simchah is a boy's name. Rabbi Nachman ben Simchah, z"ya Na Nach

Comment: I think Simchah is quite an unusual exception

Comment: @NissimNanach Simcha is used for both men and women. Chatam Sofer's daughter was called Simcha.

Comment: @MosesSupposes There's also Yonah.

Comment: @Meir I'm sure that there are a few exceptions, but it is still exceptional.  Also Yonah is also used as a female name.  My Hebrew isn't good enough to know, but I suspect that the exceptional words are where the female and male form are exactly the same, so it isn't that they aren't female words, but that they are *also* a male word

Comment: is Yehudah ever a girl's name?

Comment: Are these Talmudic or historical? I got them from ChatGPT so I'm not sure. Eliyah (אֵלִיָּה)
Yirmiyah (יִרְמְיָה)
Mattityah (מַתִּתְיָה)
Zechariyah (זְכַרְיָה)
Netanyah (נְתַנְיָה). The Zekharyah is for sure